# R - object not found error when it exists

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to understand why "R" cannot find a variable that is definitely in my dataframe.

Here is the dput for "DF.1" in my code below:

```r
library("dplyr")
library("stringr")
DF.1 <- structure(list(`ID` = c("APP-5XUEJHC1XN-2019", 
    "APP-AVO1K5F33B-2019", "APP-J12JZHOWTM-2019", "APP-VROJDQSZ3P-2019", 
    "APP-00AURK6GEP-2019", "APP-00VACS4YZI-2018", "APP-00W7N0XXSO-2019", 
    "APP-01AQMLSHX6-2019", "APP-021R8JXC6O-2018", "APP-022XIXHHIQ-2019", 
    "APP-025ZNBC262-2018", "APP-02IUB6YJ05-2019", "APP-02PSFXZI1U-2019", 
    "APP-02TZN2M3JT-2019", "APP-034IPEAN7E-2018", "APP-03XWZT90ZW-2018", 
    "APP-040I2UPEEI-2019", "APP-0442F1YUCB-2019", "APP-04DKWB5EF3-2019", 
    "APP-04E58XMYDH-2018"), `Observations` = c("Single", 
    "Single", "Single", "Single", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))

DF.2 <- DF.1 %>% dplyr::mutate(
    "New Var" = case_when(
        str_detect(tolower(`Observations`), "single") ~ "Single Protocol",
        str_detect(tolower(`Observations`), "multiple") |
            !(str_detect(tolower(`Observations`), paste(c("single", "multiple"), collapse = '|'))) |
            is.na(`Observations`) ~ "Multiple Protocol"))
```

When I run the above code, I get the following error:

```
Error in eval_tidy(pair$lhs, env = default_env) : 
  object 'Observations' not found
```

The variable is in the dataframe, so I am wondering if there is a conflict with either **case_when** or **str_detect**.

Comment: What is `Observations` and why do you use ` ?

Comment: It is an open text field and I use it to create another variable (new_var) as it contains the words single or multiple as per the str_detect function.

Comment: The code (as currently formatted) runs without error for me.

Comment: Weird. It worked for me previously, but all of a sudden started kicking me out this error. Is there something in my environment that could cause this?

Answer (score 2):

you need to assign the `structure(...)` piece to an object (`DF.1 <- ...`):

```
DF.1 <- structure(list(`ID` = c("APP-5XUEJHC1XN-2019", 
"APP-AVO1K5F33B-2019", "APP-J12JZHOWTM-2019", "APP-VROJDQSZ3P-2019", 
"APP-00AURK6GEP-2019", "APP-00VACS4YZI-2018", "APP-00W7N0XXSO-2019", 
"APP-01AQMLSHX6-2019", "APP-021R8JXC6O-2018", "APP-022XIXHHIQ-2019", 
"APP-025ZNBC262-2018", "APP-02IUB6YJ05-2019", "APP-02PSFXZI1U-2019", 
"APP-02TZN2M3JT-2019", "APP-034IPEAN7E-2018", "APP-03XWZT90ZW-2018", 
"APP-040I2UPEEI-2019", "APP-0442F1YUCB-2019", "APP-04DKWB5EF3-2019", 
"APP-04E58XMYDH-2018"), `Observations` = c("Single", 
"Single", "Single", "Single", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Comment: I don't think that's the source of the error; if I run the code as originally formatted I get the error `Error in eval(lhs, parent, parent) : object 'DF.1' not found` rather than `Error in eval_tidy(pair$lhs, env = default_env) : object 'Observations' not found`

Comment: We know nothing about thier R environment that could cause a different error message. But it seems this worked for them.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Does anyone get the same error of "Error in eval_tidy(pair$lhs, env = default_env) : object 'Observations' not found" when you run the posted code?